# Скачивание изображений с сайта

Tags: php

Имеется такой простенький скрипт, отдающий картинки на скачивание

```
$file = ('files/'.$row['file']);
header ("Content-Type: image/".$row['type']);
header ("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file); 
readfile($file);
```

Но после того, как сохранились на компьютер? они почему-то не открываются. И что-то не пойму в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил:

```
<?
$flnm = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
 if(ini_get("zlib.output_compression")) ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "Off");
 $flxt = strtolower(substr(strrchr($flnm,"."),1));

 if(($flnm=="")||(!file_exists($flnm))){
 echo "Error: file <i>".$flnm."</i> not found."; exit;
 }

 switch($flxt){
 case "gif": $tpe="image/gif"; break;
 case "png": $tpe="image/png"; break;
 case "jpg": $tpe="image/jpg"; break;
 case "3gp": $tpe="video/3gpp"; break;
 case "jad": $tpe="text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor"; break;
 case "jar": $tpe="application/java-archive"; break;
 case "wml": $tpe="text/vnd.wap.wml"; break;
 case "wbmp": $tpe="image/vnd.wap.wbmp"; break;
 case "mid": $tpe="audio/midi"; break;
 case "mp4": $tpe="video/mp4"; break;
 case "flv": $tpe="video/x-flv"; break;
 case "ics": $tpe="text/calendar"; break;
 case "pdf": $tpe="application/pdf"; break;
 case "exe": $tpe="application/octet-stream"; break;
 case "zip": $tpe="application/zip"; break;
 case "doc": $tpe="application/msword"; break;
 case "xls": $tpe="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
 case "ppt": $tpe="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
 default: $tpe="application/force-download";
 }

 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Cache-Control: private", false); 
 header("Content-Type: ".$tpe);
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($flnm)."\";");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header("Content-Length: ".filesize($flnm));
 readfile("$flnm");
 exit();
 ?>
```

Применение, у меня:

```
header('location: /down.php?files/'.$row['file']);
```